# Using Apache's remoteip module with the HTTP Forwarded header

Tags: apache-2.4

I'm running Apache behind an Nginx reverse proxy and want to show the original source IPs of the requests in Apache's logs using the [`remoteip`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_remoteip.html) module.

The official standard header for passing that information from Nginx to Apache is [`Forwarded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Forwarded). However, `Forwarded` contains additional information aside from the original IP itself, in contrast to the common (but non-standard) `X-Forward-For`. It seems that this causes problems for `remoteip`.

Using the following Apache configuration

```
RemoteIPHeader Forwarded
LogFormat "%a <Forwarded: %{Forwarded}i>" forwarded
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/forwarded.log forwarded
```

my log entries look like this:

```
127.0.0.1 <Forwarded: for=172.16.16.1; host=my-host:443; proto=https>
```

That is, `%a` is not updated to the original IP, even though the `Forwarded` header is present.

If I configure my reverse proxy to pass just the IP using the `X-Forwarded-For` header and configure `remoteip` to use that field instead then everything works as expected.

However, I'd prefer to use the header recommended by the standard -- is there a way to do this?

I'm using Apache 2.4.10.

Answer (score 0):

The `Forwarded` header is currently not supported by `remoteip`. See [this ticket](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62377) in Apache's issue tracker.